# Air Mobile As3 App

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have been trying to get connected to my MySQL db from an Air mobile AS3 app I am making with flashdevelop.  I have been using this tutorial series from tutsplus+ as reference.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1--active-5147

I have been able to get an embedded swf with local security access to connect to the db using my login username and password as they do in the tutorial.

I spent 4 hours last night trying to find out why my air app doesn't connect when I use it from my android phone or tablet.  When I try to connect using the URLLoader I get

> IO Error #2032.

I thought the URL needed to be the full web address.  I guess I am unclear whether there needs to be something special done to get access to a php processing page on my server.  I thought under the application sandbox you had that ability.  Am I missing something?  I have tested my php handling page, and it works from the embedded swf or if I just comment out some code, so I know it is connecting, retrieving a record and printing a result, but for some reason my Air Mobile as3 code isn't doing the trick to make it work.

Here is the main connection function I am trying to get work:

```
public function processLogin ():void {
        result.text = "processing Login";
        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.websiteaddress/php/ControlPanel.php");            
        result.text = phpFileRequest.url;
        trace(phpFileRequest.url);
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;
        var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;   
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, httpHandleError);

        phpVars.systemCall = "checkLogin";
        phpVars.username = username.text;
        phpVars.password = password.text;

        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the URL in your android tablet/phone browser and see if that URL is actually accessible from your device?

Comment: Yes I can access the ControlPanel.php page from my android devices.  I can get the page to process an invalid login attempt and print a message.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your URL? I can give it a try and see? Without that really hard to say whats going on.

Comment: To access internet an android app needs to request it in its permission. Did you do that?